# Оставить строки в SQL по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть несколько условий where (допустим 10), и нужно оставить только те записи которые соответствуют по 5 и более параметрам.
Кроме как перебора, никаких мыслей нет, можно ли как то решить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любое условие (оператор `=`, например) в mysql возвращает 0 (если условие не сработало) или 1. Поэтому можно написать

```
... where ((a=1) + (b=2) + ... + (field10=X)) >= 5
```

В случае если в поле может быть NULL условия стоит писать в виде `coalesce(a=1, 0)`